# How to give border to background-image?

Tags: css

[image]

Using background image to input box and padding value would show like this:

[image]

Now how to apply border-right to the background-image?

Or, what's the best practice to make this?

---

I have just like these inputs

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

css

```
input{background: url('path') no-repeat left center; padding-left: 50px;}
```

Comment: Multiple options, border on the image, use a `:before` pseudo-element, or a real element (or if you're targeting supported browsers, multiple background images)

Comment: It depends on what your current code is. Can we see it?

Comment: added to the quesiton.

Comment: I'm not asking as my way only but best practice or say good way to accomplish this

Comment: Did you try my box-shadow method ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just add the `border-right` to the background image like so:

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]{
    background: url('http://uploadpie.com/LctRy') no-repeat left center; 
    padding: 18px 0 18px 70px;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #999;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDdLc/2/)**

Comment: There are various ways using different HTML markup. Do you need a different solution to what I have provided?

Comment: Yes a different solution. suppose if I have like this +----+[space between input and image]+----+ so I think overall css that would fit for other types of input boxes. So I'm confusing of html markup what would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Well I played with some box-shadows and I came up with this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/qY5NA/1/)**

```
input[type="text"] {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 60px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/m8lJN4g.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: inset -175px 0px #fff, inset -176px 0px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: It is working in ff too. Just that the length of shadow is larger.

Comment: +1. nice one but with box-shadow I don't ummmm want to get suggestion for html markup that would be better to use. thanks.

Comment: I didn't get that. Are you saying you don't want to change the html markup ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add border to the background image. If you are not targeting for browsers from IE6. If you are checking from IE6 then you have to wrap the textbox within span or div and add background image to div. Hope this helps.